# How do you get the source element which fired an event when using an object method

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

When you do

```
event.addeventlistener("event", somefunction, false);
```

`somefunction` gets called with `this` set to the element on which the event fired and gets called with the event. However, `event.target` is not the same as `this`.

This makes for problems if I want to go for a more OO approach and put `somefunction` into my class and use `bind`, or make my class support the `EventListener` API. Because at that point, I'll be called with `this` set to the instance of my class. I can find no documented way of getting hold of that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered that an event object has a `currentTarget` property. which is precisely what the 'this' is set to. Couldn't find any documentation that said that explicitly though.

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` is the element what has triggered the event, while `this` the element what has the event listener registered on.

An Example:

In the script below, the `a` element has the listener. But whenever you click on the text inside the `span` it will become the `target`. From the target upwards, the event is given to all parent elements. This is called *event bubbling*.

```js
var e = document.getElementById('this');
e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('this:  ', this);
  console.log('target:', event.target);
});
```

```html
<a id="this" href="#">
  <span id="target">click me</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Not sure how that addresses my problem

Answer (score 0):

If `somefunction` is a property of an object, and you want that object to be referenceable inside the function (via `this`), then you can't use the same `this` for the element that triggered the event - somehow, you'll have to have the default `this` from inside the handler to the function. Here's one possibility, use an anonymous function that grabs the `this` and the event from inside the handler and calls the object's method with those as parameters:

```js
const obj = {
  bar(listenerElement, event) {
    console.log('this.data: ' + this.data);
    console.log('listener element ID: ' + listenerElement.id);
    console.log('event target ID: ' + event.target.id);
  },
  data: 'data'
}

document.querySelector('#outer').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  obj.bar(this, event);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ohh, ok, i'll have a play with that. I'd like to avoid singletons but I think I can do something like that